# Why `z-index` have no effect on my elements?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, frontend

I have a modal, which when opened has a gray background overlay.
As you can see in the photo, an element is placed on this overlay, even though it has a lower `z-index` than my modal overlay!

[image]

No matter how much I try to implement all kinds of methods to fix this problem, I didn't get any results, I also tested all kinds of `position`s.

now this is my modal overlay css codes:

```css
#global-modal {
    background-color: rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.2431372549);
    height: 100%;
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    position: fixed;
}
```

and this is my element's styles:

```css
.searchMain_search_container_change_way__zns8r {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 22px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 40px;
}
```

I want the modal overlay display priority to be higher

Comment: Hello, could you add some basic HTML to see about the layout ? also, you should add code with the triple backquotes, that way code will be formatted better

Comment: Please add a code example (codepen, codesandbox, ecc) to better undestand the problem

Comment: #global-modal should be position absolute and position relative to its parent in order to work with z-index

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable example, rather than CodePen, CodeSandbox, etc.. We want questions to be self-contained so that people don't have to go to other sites (which may be forbidden by work firewalls, etc.). cc @DiegoBetto

Comment: Did you try to use background-color with no transparency at all? since even if it overlaps, if the background is transparent you'll see the items below anyways.

Comment: this might help you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-z-index-not-working/